# How verify that 3 numbers in sequence are equals?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have to check if a sequence of any numbers are equals. The user will submit a sequence, and if, the numbers repeat in sequence, he won some points.

And the sequence to win the points it's a sequence of three. For example: 
1 3 4 4 4 5 
He won the points because he inputted a sequence of 3 numbers 4.

The sequence of numbers it's on a Vector. The size of the vector, It's given by the user too.

```
for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            if (M[i] == M[i + 1] && M[i + 1] == M[i+2]) {
                if (L[i] == L[i + 1] && L[i + 1] == L[i + 2]) {
                    ValuePoint = 0;
                } else {
                    PExtraM = i;
                    ValuePoint = 30;
                }

Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        R = sc1.nextInt();

        int M[] = new int[R];
        int L[] = new int[R];

        for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            M[i] = sc1.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < L.length; i++) {
            L[i] = sc1.nextInt();
        }


//The problem It's here ************************************


        for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            if (M[i] == M[i + 1] && M[i + 1] == M[i+2]) {
                if (L[i] == L[i + 1] && L[i + 1] == L[i + 2]) {
                    ValuePoint = 0;
                } else {
                    PExtraM = i;
                    ValuePoint = 30;
                }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at maratona.Maratona2.main(Maratona2.java:37)
Java Result: 1

Comment: You know that the largest value the variable "i" can have is M.length - 1, therefore you cannot access M[i + 1], and M[i + 2] since these indexes are outside of the array when i = M.length - 1.

Comment: Why are you dividing your input into 2 arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others already said, u r overshooting the boundaries of your array. You need to stop the loop 2 earlier to prevent.

You possably want to use something like that:

```
    int sequenceLength = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i <= M.length - sequenceLength; i++) {
        boolean correct = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < sequenceLength && (correct = (M[i] == M[j+i])); j++);

        if (correct){
            ValuePoint = 0;
        } else {
            PExtraM = i;
            ValuePoint = 30;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I wanted to do that. Thank's for the help. The problem was in the size of the boundaries of the array. It was going into 6, but the size was 5.

Answer (score 1):

> i < M.length

Now let's assume the length of the Vector you are saying is 5 ok? 
Now my **loop will run till i is less than 5**, right?
Now go to your next code :

```
if (M[i] == M[i + 1] && M[i + 1] == M[i+2])
```

Let's take the value of i as

> 4 (suppose)

which is in fact less than 5 and the loop condition satisfies.
But see the next code, it becomes

M[4]==M[5]&& ==M[6]

Obviously since the length of the given Vector is 5, my last element's index will be 4.
So after that **5 & 6 ** will show null only.
That's why it's saying ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception error at 5.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

your loop variable i must stop at m.length-3

```
   (i <m. length-2)
```

to have i+1=m.length-2 and i+2=m.length-1

but in your case you are trying to access i+1=m.length and i+2= m.length+1 both are out of bounds on the last two iterations